# Creating a new page and automatically associating it with a template in WordPress

Tags: php, admin

I've got three page templates called "Simple", "Front", and "Form" and I would like to add a shortcut in the admin side bar to directly create a page that would be associated with any of these templates. So below "Add new" there would be:

[image]

- Add new Simple Page
- Add new Front Page
- Add new Form Page

I've searched for it on Google but can't find any information. Is it possible to do this in WordPress?

Comment: you can create a custom templates and use that templates while creating the page.

Comment: What @phpuser said + when you click on "Add new Front Page" you send $_GET param and make changes on post editor page so "Fron" template is automatically selected. But be careful and read few articles on changing admin panel before you do it, so all your work doesn't go up in smoke on next wordpress update.

Comment: This question would be awesome for [wordpress.se]

Answer (score 2):

I found this question very interesting ,So here is what i have done to make this possible.

Fetch page template and add them as sub menu of Post type page.

```
function addTemplateAddNewSubMenu() {

    global $submenu;

    // here we are fetching all page template from current activated theme.
    $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates( 'page' );

    foreach ( $templates as $filename => $title ) {

        if ( $filename != 'default' && $filename != '' ) {

                // add page-template filename as query string to add new page link.
                $url = 'post-new.php?post_type=page&template=' . $filename;

                $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][] = array( 'Add new ' . $title , 'manage_options', $url );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'addTemplateAddNewSubMenu' );
```

I have added page template as query string to

```
/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&template=template-contact.php
```

Making page template dropdown selected by jQuery and template Query string.

```
add_action( 'admin_head','selectPageTemplate' );

function selectPageTemplate() {

    global $pagenow;

    if ( $pagenow == 'post-new.php' ) {

        if ( get_post_type() == 'page' && isset($_GET['template']) ) {

            $template = $_GET['template']; ?>

            <script>
                jQuery(function($){
                    $('#page_template').val('<?php echo $template;?>');
                });
            </script>

            <?php
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how to set the page template, for new pages, through  the custom `wpse_page_template` GET parameter:

```
https://examle.tld/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&wpse_page_template=tpl-test.php
```

We can hook into the `save_post_page` hook and target the *auto-draft* status:

```
add_action( 'save_post_page', function (  $post_ID, $post, $update )
{
    // Target 'auto-draft' status only
    if ( 'auto-draft' !== get_post_status( $post ) )
        return $post_ID;

    // User input
    $input_tpl = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'wpse_page_template', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $input_tpl = sanitize_file_name( $input_tpl );

    // Get current page templates
    $page_templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates( $post );

    // Nothing to do if user tries a non a valid page template
    if ( ! isset( $page_templates[$input_tpl] ) )
        return $post_ID;

    // Update the user defined page template
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_page_template', $input_tpl );

    return $post_ID;

}, 10, 3 );
```

This approach could be extended for custom post types in WordPress 4.7+.